# How do I give a fixed height (dynamic) list overscroll bounce even when its items have not (yet) exceeded the list container height?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, mobile, scroll

When using a fixed-height ul with overflow scroll, the list will not have an overscroll bounce effect until its items exceed the height of the list. However, on mobile, I'd like the list container to have an overscroll bounce effect even when its items have not overflowed the container. Consider iMessage for instance, even when only a single message exists in a conversation, one can still pull the list to scroll (bounce), albeit to snap back into place. This gives the user an indication that the view is a dynamic list that will be scrollable. What is a way to achieve this effect? And what is the proper term for the effect of a list having a sort of padding that a user can scroll to?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean [lazy loading](https://responsivedesign.is/strategy/content-delivery/lazy-loading-content/).